# Converting a double to a long, then back to double?

Tags: type-conversion, double, precision, long-integer

Does Converting a double to a long, then back to double, guarantees keeping the exact value to the left of the decimal point?

EDIT:
Working with C++: Conversion is as follows:

```
double d_var = func();
long l_var = (long)d_var;
d_var = (double)l_var;
```

Comment: how would you convert? By rounding down?

Comment: `2^53 + 1` is the smallest integer that cannot be represented by the `double` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every programming language I have worked with it will keep the value to the left of the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

For typecast then the fractions are removed when casting, but for range then double can hold bigger numbers than long and therefore becomes something else during a typecast.

At least for common languages I can think of.